# Liferay Theme, show component only in welcome page

Tags: liferay-6, velocity, liferay-theme

I'm editing a Liferay Theme. By editing the portal_normal.vm, I want to conditionally show or hide a component

```
#if ($is_welcome_page)
<span class="lang">
    $taglibLiferay.language("fm",null,"languageId",1)
    <br>
    <div class="my-menu">
       ...... lots of irrelevant stuff here
    </div>              
</span>
#end>
```

How can I make that `$is_welcome_page` variable become true only if the current page is the Portal's **Welcome page** ?
I guess I could get the friendly Url and check it, but I'm not sure how I can do that. Any working code would be much appreciated!

Edit: using Liferay 6.1.0 if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally customising themes per-page is a bad practice (theme should be global or customized for a specific site). To do it correctly, you should just add language portlet on your main site instead of hardcoding it within a theme template.

Anyway, if you really want to do it, you have access to the `layout` object (directly or via `$layout = $theme.getLayout()`), which in Liferay is a representation of a page (for example it has `getFriendlyURL()` method). Check [Liferay Wiki](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+Objects+from+Velocity) for the list of all variables accessible from Velocity, there are lots of others properties you could use, for example `the_title`.

This is a theme customization, so a good practice is to put all custom settings within Theme Settings. You can read how to do it in [Liferay's documentation](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/settin-4).

Comment: thanx for pointing me to the right places. Your advice on leaving the portlet out of the theme is also very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I did it, thanx to @Krzysztof Gołębiowski

```
        #set($testPageName = $theme.getLayout().getFriendlyURL())
        #set($layout = $theme.getLayout())
        #set($currPageName = $layout.getFriendlyURL())
        #set($isWelcomPage = $currPageName == "/home")

        #if ($isWelcomPage)
         <span class="lang">
            $taglibLiferay.language("fm",null,"languageId",1)


            <br>
        #end
```